# Matlab search in a website and get results

Tags: matlab, web-search

I would like to perform a search in a website (every time searching different terms) and get results in matlab platform.

Do you know any easy and reliable method to perform this?

Thanks in advance.
LK

Comment: Could you please more specific in the description and provide an example?
You can use webread to read webpages and strfind to search for strings, but i'm not sure that's what you want.

Comment: Yooyle thanks for your answer. I would like to perform a search in a website using the matlab platform, i.e. to write something in the search field of the website and get the search results by only using Matlab.

Comment: https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/375862-input-to-a-web-page-with-script

Here is a relevant thread on the topic. If you could share the website you are trying to use we could figure out something more precisely.